# Set a text inside a circle in phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm creating my first phaser 3 game. I'm trying to create a container in the shape of a circle with a text inside it. here is my current code:

```
this.circle = this.add.circle(0, 0, gameOptions.wheelRadius / 3, 0xa60e1a);
var textConfig = {fontSize:'20px', color:'white', fontFamily: 'Arial'};
this.Text = this.add.text(0, 0, "میخوای بچرخونی؟", textConfig);
this.myBtn = this.add.container(gameConfig.width / 2, gameConfig.height / 2, [this.circle, this.Text]);
this.myBtn.setSize(this.circle.width, this.circle.height);
```

but the text doesn't set inside the circle properly and half of the text is out of circle.
to be clear, I want the circle to be like a button with an inner text.
I'll appreciate any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *simple* and fast solution is to use the *builtin* phaser function `Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center(...);`

Here the [link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Display.Align.In.html#.Center__anchor), and here is a [link to some great examples](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/category/display/align) for the many `Align.In` Namespace.

**Here your code slightly modified:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
        create
    },
    banner: false
}; 

function create () {
    this.circle = this.add.circle(0, 0, 50, 0xa60e1a);
    var textConfig = {fontSize:'20px', color:'white', fontFamily: 'Arial'};
    this.Text = this.add.text(0, 0, "test text", textConfig);
    this.myBtn = this.add.container(config.width / 2, config.height / 2, [this.circle, this.Text]);
    Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center( this.Text, this.circle );
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```